# "Fuzzier" search in mysql

Tags: mysql, search

My client, upon seeing the search feature I've written into his site, has asked me to make it "fuzzier" meaning that it should be more general - presumably to return more search results.

I'm not clear on how to do this. Currently, for every section, I search the table in the database (every column) for a value `LIKE` the search query.

The case I was given was this:

The table has a row where a `complexname` has a value of "Larae's Corner", but a search for "Larae" doesn't return it as a result.

As far as I'm aware, checking every column value for every row in the table for anything LIKE the search query is as "fuzzy" as anyone can ever get.

Can anyone help me with this at all? I'm looking for concept here. I need to understand how search works in more detail than just LIKE...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at MySQL's [full text search functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). With its [natural language searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html), it might be enough for your needs. InnoDB supports full text search since MySQL 5.6 (before, only MyISAM tables had this feature).

If that's not enough, you might need a dedicated tool for searching, like [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) (or, if you're using Java and want to interface with Solr's underlying search engine directly, [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/)). Other popular choices include [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) (which also uses Lucene under its hood) and [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

A key part in the inner workings of a search engine is [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming), which [duffymo mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18186700/1071311).

**Edit:**

Here's a list of index-compatible [Lucene implementations in different languages](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneImplementations).

Comment: hmmm have implemented fulltext, but the case my client gave me is unchanged :/ I'm working on a .NET system so I'm not sure if any of the other options will fit...

Comment: You implemented full text search in unter 10 minutes? Really? Really really? Also, the other options are pleasantly programming language-agnostic, so I don't know why there would be a problem. And last but not least, [here's a Lucene implementation in .NET](http://lucenenet.apache.org/).

Comment: Well, I added the FULLTEXT index on the columns and changed my SP to use Match (...) AGAINST (...)... what else is there?

Answer (score 0):

You do indeed need something fuzzier than LIKE.  I'd recommend looking at word stems and indexing with a tool like Lucene.